# How do you display text from a user input? Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface

I am new to the language of swift (3.0). I am working on a new application for iOS. How can I create a textbox where a user types in input, presses a button, then displays the text under the button? Thanks!

Comment: This might be a good place to start: [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html). More resources available at https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this either using storyboards or programmatically. Both options works as of **Xcode 8 Swift 3**

**Storyboards**

1. Drag in a `UITextField`, a `UIButton` and `UILabel` from the library, onto you view controller
2. Create an IBOutlet for the `UITextField` and the `UILabel`  to your `ViewController.swift` file.
3. Then create an IBAction for the `UIButton` to the same `ViewController.swift` file.
4. Write this code in the action function for your button:

   `myLabel.text = myTextField.text`

Your whole code should look like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func myButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    myLabel.text = myTextField.text

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
}
```

Or **Programmatically:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// First create your components

let myTextField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.backgroundColor = .lightGray //Just so you can see it
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textField
}()

let myLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Label text" //You may want to set this to something else to start with
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let myButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Press me", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

//Then add them as subViews in the viewDidLoad method and set some constraints. 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(myTextField)
    myTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    myTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: myTextField, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: myTextField, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: -100).isActive = true

    view.addSubview(myLabel)
    myLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    myLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: myLabel, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: myLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true


    view.addSubview(myButton)
    myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    myButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: myButton, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: myButton, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myTextField, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10).isActive = true

//This sets the function for when the button is pressed 
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.myButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
}

//Add code here to when the button is pressed
func myButtonPressed() {

    myLabel.text = myTextField.text

}

}
```